# Get camera preview frame from surface view camera2 api

Tags: android, camera, frame, qr-code, android-camera2

I have been trying to get a camera preview frame for a day now using camera2 api but did not get any success. I have found a few solutions but did not able to implement those. So if anyone can give a simple and straight way to implement that would be great.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem or should I update it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should set a target surface to get an image from it.

```
mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

imageReader =  ImageReader.newInstance(currentWidth, currentHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, MAX_IMAGES);

List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();

outputSurfaces.add(imageReader.getSurface()); // here add as many surface as you want
mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget()//this function allow you to set targets
```

and this callback allow you to retrive frames

```
readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                  image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if(image == null){
                    //System.out.println("it is null image"); // image reader did not get new image
                    return;
                }
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                  if(planes[0].getBuffer() == null){ // here 0 indicates first target I set in outputSurfaces list
                      System.out.println("it is null object reference of planes");
                    return;
                  }
                 //.... do whatever you want here

                //After you are done with an image then close it 
               image.close(); 

               }
}
```

For full example please refer [Google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)